# How can i deploy django(using python3) on a Windows computer that already has python2 in it's system PATH?

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I wrote my project in python 3 and django 2.0. The deployment environment has another program that relies on it's built in python 2,and whenever it starts it writes it's python 2 path to the system environment variable,so my Django project can never run normally since it finds the wrong version of python.

I'm using Windows server 2008 + Apache + mod_wsgi as the deployment environment.

How can I deploy my Django project successfully without using any aggressive strategy(like deleting other python paths and add mine)?

Comment: Look into [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)

Comment: try virtualenv..

Comment: What version of Python was mod_wsgi compiled for? What version is used it dictated by that, not anything at runtime. Of course if you have both Python 2 and Python 3 web applications you want to run with mod_wsgi, your out of luck on Windows unless you run two separate Apache instances. IOW, virtual environments alone, as suggested by others, is not enough when using mod_wsgi.